# Angular Promises Chaining Sequentially

Tags: angularjs, azure-storage, angular-promise, ng-file-upload

I am working on with angular Upload to upload file to Azure Storage.

```
 var filePath = [];
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/uploadFile',
            data: { file: $scope.selectedFile }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            //resp.data contains URL returned from upload
            filePath.push(resp.data);
        })
```

i would need to perform the file upload for 3 times, which is needed to perform in sequential manner, example :

```
upload [file 1], get [file 1] URL, 
upload [file 2], get [file 2] URL, 
upload [file 3], get [file 3] URL
```

file2 need to wait for file1 to complete before it is started,
and file3 need to wait for file2 to complete before it is started,

how can i use promises to make sure i get the file URL in sequential pattern?

eg : filePath[file1URL, file2URL, file3URL]

Answer (score 0):

You can do

 `var filePath = [];
        Upload.upload({
            url: '/uploadFile',
            data: { file: $scope.selectedFile1 }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            filePath.push(resp.data);
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/uploadFile',
                data: { file: $scope.selectedFile2 }
            }).then(function (resp) {
                filePath.push(resp.data);
                 Upload.upload({...
            })
        })`

To make sure you upload after the previous file is uploaded.